# Essential Training Topics for Supervisors of ASP.NET Developers

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, fortran

I have a co-worker who supervises a group of ASP.NET developers who are doing lots of ASP.NET/SQL Server apps. My co-worker was very technical at one time, but his last programming assignment was writing Fortran code in the 1980s.

He has asked me to help him gain a deeper knowledge of ASP.NET Web application development to equip him in his supervisory role.  I will be spending an hour every other week with him providing training, and he will probably not have a lot of time to commit otherwise.

What would you recommend as topics to cover, tutorial resources, etc. so that I can help him get up to speed in his role as a supervisor of ASP.NET developers?

Comment: What qualifies your coworker to supervise ASP.NET/SQL Server developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow... Fortran to ASP.NET is a huge leap.

Google "ASP.NET interview" and you will see a few exhaustive lists of specific stuff.

My broad priorities would be:

HTTP and basic client/server interaction
ASP.NET Page Lifecycle
MS SQL Server basics and SQL queries
ASP.NET security (authorization, avoiding SQL injection, etc)
Databinding
User Controls

In the end... he's just going to have to dive in and work with it to get a handle on it.

Comment: And of course some C# syntax possibly including Linq if you use it.